# Monogo aggregate query taking too long on server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am trying to use aggregate framework in mongo for some data stats. the query i am using, when run on local is hardly taking a a minute but when i run the same query on server it does not give response and after keep on waiting for too long , i had to cancel it, can anyone please suggest why is this happening.

```
var orderIds = db.delivery.find({"status":"DELIVERED"}).map(function(o) {
    return o.order 
}); 

var userIds =  db.order.aggregate([{
    $match : { _id : { $in : orderIds } }
}, {
    $group: { _id : "$customer" }
}]).map(function(u) { return u._id });

var userstats = db.order.aggregate([{
    $sort : { customer : 1, dateCreated : 1 }
}, {
    $match : { status : "DELIVERED", customer : {  $in : userIds } }
}, { 
    $group: {
        _id : "$customer", orders : { $sum : 1 }, 
        firstOrderDate : { $first : "$dateCreated" },
        lastOrderDate : { $last : "$dateCreated" }
    }
}]);

userstats.forEach(function(x) { 
    db.user.update({ _id : x._id }, {
        $set : { 
            totalOrders : x.orders,
            firstOrderDate : x.firstOrderDate,
            lastOrderDate : x.lastOrderDate
        }
    })
})
```

I am not sure , but shouldn't it be more fast on server ? , but instead its not able to give output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To speed up the process you could refactor your operations in a couple of ways. 
The first would be to eliminate unnecessary pipeline operations like the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator which could be replaced with the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** and **[`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min)** operators within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline.

Secondly, use the **[`bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** API which will increase perfromance on update operations especially when dealing with large collections since they will be sending the operations to the server in batches (for example, say a batch size of 500) unlike sending every request to the server (as you are currently doing with the update statement within the `forEach()` loop).

Consider the following refactored operations:

```
var orderIds = db.delivery.find({"status": "DELIVERED"}).map(function(d){return d.order;}),
    counter = 0,
    bulk = db.user.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

var userstatsCursor = db.orders.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": orderIds } } },
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$customer", 
            "orders": { "$sum": 1 },
            "firstOrderDate": { "$min": "$dateCreated" },
            "lastOrderDate":{ "$max": "$dateCreated" } } 
        } 
    }
]);

userstatsCursor.forEach(function (x){
    bulk.find({ "_id": x._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { 
            "totalOrders": x.orders,
            "firstOrderDate": x.firstOrderDate,
            "lastOrderDate": x.lastOrderDate
        }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(); // Execute per 500 operations and 
        // re-initialize every 500 update statements
        bulk = db.user.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clean up remaining operations in queue
if (counter % 500 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

Comment: the solution looks good, i can see a lot of new things, but the query is somehow throwing the syntax error "Unexpected token  }"

Comment: @user29578 There was a typo, I removed an extra closing brace before the pipeline array in my updated answer. Give that a try again.

Comment: hi chridam , i am getting this error 2016-02-14T02:32:33.615+0530 TypeError: Object function () {
    return new Bulk(this, false);
  } has no method 'find'
    at (shell):1:436
    at Object.DBQuery.forEach (src/mongo/shell/query.js:281:9)
    at (shell):1:409

Comment: @user29578 Which MongoDB version are you using and which method did you try?

Comment: i am using 2.7.2, i am trying to run the same query from your answer , but it is throwing this error for find method on bulk, dont know why

Comment: @user29578 Another typo once again, initializing the `bulk` instance was typed wrongly, it should be `bulk = db.user.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();` instead of `bulk = db.user.initializeUnorderedBulkOp;`, check updated answer, my apologies.

Comment: correct me please for this, when i use no of operation 500 then it shows nMatched:113 and for no of operation 1000 , it shows 613,for different values of counter i get different  nMatched, nMatched is number of documents updates, should it be same everytime ?

Comment: from the documentation it says that no of update operations is nMatched, so for me i am updating all users with delivered orders, which are somewhere around 30k, can you please tell me why is it showing such less number and that too different with bulk size ?

Comment: @user29578 Please create a new question for this

Comment: created question, please check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395630/bulkwriteresult-in-mongo-nmatched-and-no-of-documents-does-not-match

Comment: hi, can i remind you for this question , appreciate if you can help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395630/bulkwriteresult-in-mongo-nmatched-and-no-of-documents-updated-does-not-match

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you make `$match` the first operation in your pipeline as the `$match` operator can only use an index if it is first in the aggregation pipeline:

```
var userstats = db.order.aggregate([{
    $match : {
        status :"DELIVERED", 
        customer : { $in : userIds }
    }
}, {
    $sort : {
        customer : 1,
        dateCreated : 1
    }
}, { 
    $group : {  
        _id : "$customer",
        orders : { $sum : 1 }, 
        firstOrderDate: { $first : "$dateCreated" },
        lastOrderDate : { $last:"$dateCreated" }
    }
}]);
```

You should also add an index on `status` and `customer` if you have not already defined one:

```
db.delivery.createIndex({status:1,customer:1})
```

Comment: any help on this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403356/mongo-find-query-on-joda-datetime