# mongo find query on joda datetime

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jodatime

i am trying to use find query in mongodb to determine the records on that specific date , the query is working fine when i pass it the normal date object and if i find according to dateCreated field, but for joda date field, i don't know how should i form a joda date

right now i am using this query for normal records

```
var from =  new Date('2015-05-18T00:00:00.000Z'); 
var to =  new Date('2016-05-19T00:00:00.000Z'); 
db.delivery.find( {"dateCreated" : { $gte:from,$lt:to } } );
```

now i also have a field called deliveryDate which is of type joda date and stored like this

```
"deliveryDate" : {
    "jodaType" : "org.joda.time.DateTime",
    "interval_start" : ISODate("2015-03-28T18:30:00Z"),
    "interval_end" : ISODate("2015-03-28T18:30:00Z"),
    "jodaField_zone" : "UTC",
    "time" : NumberLong("1427567400000"),
    "jodaField_dayOfMonth" : 28,
    "jodaField_hourOfDay" : 18,
    "jodaField_minuteOfHour" : 30,
    "jodaField_millisOfSecond" : 0,
    "jodaField_monthOfYear" : 3,
    "jodaField_year" : 2015
},
```

i googled a lot but with no success, i have no idea how can i query for joda date ,please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joda date is serialised into a nested JSON object. You should be able to query on it using `interterval_start`

```
db.delivery.find( {"deliveryDate.interval_start" : { $gte:from,$lt:to } } );
```

Comment: appreciate if you can have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405756/mongodb-reverting-the-saved-transaction-on-exception

Comment: please guide , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418529/mongo-map-reduce-query-working-fine-for-single-document-but-not-for-all-record