# Mongodb reverting the saved transaction on exception

Tags: mongodb, grails, transactions

i am having starnge scenario in my grails application whenever different user places the order at same time and same menu is updated it throws a optimistic locking exception, now it goes like this

```
 def orderApi {
          // credits are deducted before try catch
           // code
          // .....
  try {
        // code to place order
}
catch(Exception e){
    // send mail for exception
    orderFailed = true
}

if(orderFailed){
    refundUserCredits(order)
}
}


 def refunduserCredits(Order order){
      User user = order.user
      user.credits = order.credits
      if(!user.save()){
         println "Unable to save user"  // but it does not save the credits 

             }
}
```

i guess since i catched the exception , and refund the credits and save the user object it should save them. also the strange thing is if it not saving the user credits it should come in !user.save() and print the message , but it is not even doing that.help !

Comment: Does it throw another exception by any chance ?

Comment: no there was no other exception as i checked from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit from using a [transaction](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/services.html#transactionsRollbackAndTheSession). It would allow you to bundle the order placement and credit deduction together as one all-or-nothing unit. Right now you're implementing your own transaction management. It would go something like this...

```
Order.withTransaction { status ->
    // deduce credits and attempt to place order. save() all you want.

    if(orderFailed) status.setRollbackOnly()
}
```

So the order and user changes are only persisted if all goes well.

Comment: for some reason , you can say the already implemented code complexity and large modifications , i can not attempt this, i had to figure out a solution to save the user credit once the exception is thrown.