# Mongo- Map reduce query working fine for single document, but not for all records

Tags: mongodb, grails, mapreduce

i am using the map reduce framework to determine the stats of user like this. trying to find out lastOrderDate and totalOrders for each user.

```
db.order.mapReduce(function() { 
emit (this.customer,{count:1,orderDate:this.orderDate.interval_start}) },
function(key,values){  
    var sum =0 ; var lastOrderDate; 
values.forEach(function(value) {
  lastOrderDate=value['orderDate']; sum+=value['count'];  }); 
        return 
        {totalOrder:sum,lastOrderDate:lastOrderDate}; 
    },
  { 
query:{
status:"DELIVERED","customer":ObjectId("545f64e7e4b07a0a501276db")
},
  out:"order_total"}).find()
```

which gives me absolutely correct result like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545f64e7e4b07a0a501276db"), 
"value" : { "totalOrder" : 21, "lastOrderDate" : ISODate("2015-10-02T18:30:00Z") } }
```

but when i am using the same query for all user , i just removed the customer filter from query which is

```
                  "customer":ObjectId("545f64e7e4b07a0a501276db")}
```

now when i run the query again it showing wrong and strange output like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5443765ae4b05294c8944d5b"), "value" : { "count" : 1, "orderDate" : ISODate("2014-10-18T18:30:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54561911e4b07a0a501276af"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : 2, "lastOrderDate" : ISODate("2015-03-14T18:30:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54561b9ce4b07a0a501276b1"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : NaN, "lastOrderDate" : null } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5458712ee4b07a0a501276c2"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : 2, "lastOrderDate" : ISODate("2014-11-03T18:30:00Z") } }
  // check this user
  { "_id" : ObjectId("545f64e7e4b07a0a501276db"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : NaN, "lastOrderDate" : null } }
  //
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54690771e4b0070527c657ed"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : NaN, "lastOrderDate" : ISODate("2015-11-02T18:30:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54696c64e4b07f3c07010b4a"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : 2, "lastOrderDate" : ISODate("2015-11-15T18:30:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("546980d1e4b07f3c07010b4d"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : 4, "lastOrderDate" : ISODate("2015-03-24T18:30:00Z") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54699ac4e4b07f3c07010b51"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : NaN, "lastOrderDate" : null } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54699d0be4b07f3c07010b55"), "value" : { "totalOrder" : NaN, "lastOrderDate" : null } }
```

As you can see now it is showing the different output for same user , which is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545f64e7e4b07a0a501276db"), 
"value" : { "totalOrder" : NaN, "lastOrderDate" : null } }
```

I am new to map reduce in mongo, help !

Comment: I'd suggest you to update post along with sample MongoDB documents.

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming that the order of the items returned with your customer criteria is the same as that returned without it. Your reduce function just returns the last (sequentially) orderDate value, but this isn't guaranteed to be the most recent date. FWIW -- consider using the aggregation framework for stats like this -- it has available functions for $max and $sum.